# android - image resize stopped to work - ScaleDrawable, setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I had the following code to resize image:

```
int size = `textView.getLineHeight()`;
Drawable drawable =  caller.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable);
drawable = new ScaleDrawable(drawable, 0, size, size).getDrawable();
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

That code worked without problems and suddenly stopped (the image is not resized and is displayed in full size). I'm not even sure what caused that. I'm 99.99% sure I didn't change anything in the code. However I reorganized a bit my drawable folders. Either it's somehow related with some files eclipse automatically dowloads regularly.

Concluding how to resize image to have it equal to `textView.getLineHeight()`(Please note that using two views ImageView and TextView is not a good solution in my case, so I would prefer to focus how to resize bitmap itself).